# Error installing Kinetics Ros on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ros

I'm trying to install kinetics ros on ubuntu 16.04, followig the guide http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu

The problem starts when I code this in terminal:
`sudo apt-get update`
The resume of the result is this:

```
W: The repository «http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $ (lsb_release Release» does not have a Publication file.
N: Data from a repository like this cannot be authenticated and therefore its use is potentially dangerous.
N: See the apt-secure (8) manual page for details on creating repositories and configuring users.
E: Failed to get http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/-sc)/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Some index files could not be downloaded, omitted, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm new in this, so I suposed that the problem was kind of resolved using the 'old ones instead'.
So I've continued with the guide and I code this in terminal:
`sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full`

And the resume of the result is the following:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
  ros-kinetic-eigen-stl-containers
  ros-kinetic-geometric-shapes
  ros-kinetic-collada-urdf
  ros-kinetic-robot-model
  ros-kinetic-robot
  ros-kinetic-desktop
  ros-kinetic-simulators
  ros-kinetic-desktop-full
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I dont know if this two problem are related, but I dont know how to start to fix its.
I apreciate your help.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think something went wrong when you did Step 1.2 of the instructions. These two lines look very wrong:

```
«http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $ (lsb_release Release»
http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/-sc)/binary-amd64/Packages
```

`lsb_release` is a command that was meant to be executed in that step, and the result should have been added to the apt source. Instead, it seems, it was just added as a string.

Please execute once more:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

and make sure that no space is introduced anywhere when you do that. To check that it worked, verify that you get:

```
> cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main
```

If you do, then run `sudo apt-get update` once more. After that

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

should succeed.